# Android Socket/ServerSocket vs URLConnection

Tags: c#, android, sockets

I have a Android <-> Server (C#) system that passes strings between eachother via sockets/serverSockets.It all works nice when they are both on the same LAN, but if the Android is not on the LAN then, I can't receive the data (NATs, port forwardings and so) on the Android client, because of blocked ports by mobile internet providers.

Can I replace the sockets with urlconnection?I am only passing strings.

Comment: So the android client can connect and send data? And that data is received by your server? But data sent by the server is not received by client?

Comment: Outside of LAN: Android can connect and send data, but it cannot receive because of Mobile service ISP NATs.

Comment: Very strange. Very strange.